# Why is my jQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just finished the introductory course on Codecademy and I wanted to use it on a web project but I can't seem to get it working.

test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="font-family: verdana;">wfef</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    };
});
```

Comment: Your code has a syntax error.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console (usually Ctrl+Shift+J)?

Comment: You haven't closed the parentheses starting with `click`.

Comment: Try to run your code, and look at what the browser console tells you. @Musa is correct in pointing out your code, as it is, has syntax errors and cannot possible run.

Comment: you are missing a paranthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code. You've omitted a closing parenthesis. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
 });     // added a ) here.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function() {
       $(this).hide();
    }); // Missed ')' to close click function
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you correct your actual javascript as suggested in other posts, make sure that the browser can actually find your file, test.js.  In chrome you can hit ctrl + shift + j and look at the console for errors and make sure that your file can actually be found.  It should be in the same directory as your other html file.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }); //Syntax error here! Required a ) brace to close your .click(function () {
});
```